# Active navbar is not stay highlight

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to this website, and for coding, I'm trying to highlight the active menu item. I have been searching for almost two weeks, but it is still not resolved. I have tried with Jquery CDN; it works, but when I upload all this to the web, it doesn't work. When I click the menu, it highlights, then disappears suddenly. So it didn't work with Jquery CDN. Here is the `script` tag I have used to link to the Jquery CDN.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('click', 'ul li', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
  })
</script>
```

And here is a CodePen demonstrating the problem: https://codepen.io/lukeroy/pen/PoZWpKm

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>New order</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  
  </head>
<body class="dahshat-board">

    <div id="main-wrap">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                        
          <div class="sidebar-pinner">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="scrollNav">


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mobileNav" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                          <li class="active" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="nav-bottom">
      <div class="container">
          <ul class="nav page-navigation">
                                    <li class="active" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                    
                                                                              </ul>
          </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Main variables *content* --> 
  


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#toi").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#main-wrap").toggleClass("launched");
  });
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $('#main-wrap').removeClass('launched');
    $(".mobileSearch a").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".search-bar").toggleClass("toggleSearch");
    });
  } else {
    $('#main-wrap').addClass('launched');
  }
  /*$(window).scroll(function() {
      var nav = $('#scrollNav');
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 10) {
          nav.addClass('fixedNav');
      } else {
          nav.removeClass('fixedNav');
      }
  });*/
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
}
.dahshat-board .navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: none;
}
.nav-bottom {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
.nav.page-navigation {
    background: #fad534;
    border-radius: 500px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.08);
    justify-content: center;
}
.nav.page-navigation li {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: auto;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 0 0 10.85%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.nav-bottom .nav .dropdown li {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
.nav-bottom .nav li .ico {
    margin-right: 4px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: #2b1f60;
    border-color: #2b1f60;
}
.nav-bottom .nav li.active .ico {
    background: #fad534;
    border-color: #fad534;
}
.nav-bottom .nav li.active .ico img {
    filter: invert(1) brightness(100%) saturate(0);
}
.nav-bottom .nav li a {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 44px;
    color: #2a1e5e;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2px 9px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    white-space: pre;
    width:100%;
}
.nav-bottom .nav li.dropdown.open a.dropdown-toggle {
    /* background: transparent;
    border: none; */
}
.nav-bottom .nav li a:hover,
.nav-bottom .nav li a:active,
.nav-bottom .nav li a:focus {
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
}
.nav-bottom .nav .dropdown li a {
    line-height: 18px;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.nav-bottom .nav .dropdown li a .badge {
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 13px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.nav-bottom .nav li.active a {
    color: #fad534;
    background-color: #270044;
}
.nav-bottom .nav .dropdown li a::after,
.nav-bottom .nav .dropdown li a::before {
    display: none;
}
.navbar-collapse.mobileNav{
    padding:0;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.mobileNav ul.navbar-nav.nav {
    display: none;
}
.nav-bottom .nav li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu a {
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #2a1e5e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $("#toi").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#main-wrap").toggleClass("launched");
  });


  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $('#main-wrap').removeClass('launched');
    $(".mobileSearch a").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".search-bar").toggleClass("toggleSearch");
    });
  } else {
    $('#main-wrap').addClass('launched');
  }
  /*$(window).scroll(function() {
      var nav = $('#scrollNav');
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 10) {
          nav.addClass('fixedNav');
      } else {
          nav.removeClass('fixedNav');
      }
  });*/

  $(document).on('click', 'ul li', function(){
      $("ul li").removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

```css
    

.dahshat-board .navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: none;
}
.nav-bottom {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
.nav.page-navigation {
    background: #fad534;
    border-radius: 500px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.08);
    justify-content: center;
}
.nav.page-navigation li {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: auto;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 0 0 10.85%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.nav-bottom .nav .dropdown li {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
.nav-bottom .nav li .ico {
    margin-right: 4px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: #2b1f60;
    border-color: #2b1f60;
}
.nav-bottom .nav li.active .ico {
    background: #fad534;
    border-color: #fad534;
}
.nav-bottom .nav li.active .ico img {
    filter: invert(1) brightness(100%) saturate(0);
}
.nav-bottom .nav li a {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 44px;
    color: #2a1e5e;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2px 9px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    white-space: pre;
    width:100%;
}
.nav-bottom .nav li.dropdown.open a.dropdown-toggle {
    /* background: transparent;
    border: none; */
}
.nav-bottom .nav li a:hover,
.nav-bottom .nav li a:active,
.nav-bottom .nav li a:focus {
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
}
.nav-bottom .nav .dropdown li a {
    line-height: 18px;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.nav-bottom .nav .dropdown li a .badge {
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 13px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.nav-bottom .nav li.active a {
    color: #fad534;
    background-color: #270044;
}
.nav-bottom .nav .dropdown li a::after,
.nav-bottom .nav .dropdown li a::before {
    display: none;
}
.navbar-collapse.mobileNav{
    padding:0;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.mobileNav ul.navbar-nav.nav {
    display: none;
}
.nav-bottom .nav li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu a {
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #2a1e5e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>New order</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body class="dahshat-board">

    <div id="main-wrap">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                        
          <div class="sidebar-pinner">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="scrollNav">


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mobileNav" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                          <li class="active" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="nav-bottom">
      <div class="container">
          <ul class="nav page-navigation">
                                    <li class="active" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                    
                                                                              </ul>
          </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Main variables *content* --> 
  



</body>
</html>
```

First remove active class from all **li** tags by using  **$("ul li").removeClass('active');**
,After that add active class to the clicked item by using  **$(this).addClass('active');**

Comment: thank you very much friend. it did work without uploading it to web. after i launch the website its not working. after i click the menu it is highlighted and then suddenly it disappear. any suggestions?

Comment: can u please share the **url** of your websitte?

Comment: im not launch it without fixing the issue. but here is the navbar. please check.  codepen.io/lukeroy/pen/PoZWpKm